# Why does this textView expands to the left beyond its parent borders?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a TextView and an ImageView, with a Space between them. I want the ImageView to be on the right of the TextView, and the TextView to dinamically change its size. I managed to do that but the textView expands to the left beyond its parent borders if the text is too long. Why is this happening? What can I do to fix it?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/received"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="@drawable/received_style"
        android:text="dsssssajhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhoooooooooohsssssssssdhsfsd"
        />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/edit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Found an error! the layout_width of the LinearLayout is "wrap_content", not "match_parent". Now the code is as it is on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put weight for TextView.

```
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

A `LinearLayout` gives each child at least as much space as it requests.

You can use a `RelativeLayout` instead, align the `ImageView` at parent right and the `TextView` at the `ImageView`.

Comment: I don't want the ImageView to be aligned at parent right, but dinamically positioned at the right of the textView.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/received"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"
        android:text="dsssssajhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhoooooooooohsssssssssdhsfsd"
        />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/edit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope to help you !